# How to make an app register any touches towards the screen without disabling the web views native event listeners?

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, event-handling, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using Titanium Appcelerator for building an iPad app. One of the things I need to do is to count how many times the screen is touched over a period. So basically, all I want, is to register every single click/swipe/hold/etc, which is done to the iPad screen, WITHOUT disabling all the native behaviors of the uiwebview.

I've been researching a "little" (a very lot) on this topic, and it seems that you can't have event listeners checking for these things, without disabling the webview's way off handling the gestures? But I thought that maybe a workaround is possible, it can't be impossibly to just register all gestures on the screen?
Please be aware that I know absolutely nothing of objective C … :S

Thank you (:

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

This allows the gestures to be shared between your own gesture recognizer and the UIWebView.
You'll have to call it for each type of gesture recognizer you register.

Comment: this question is for Titanium. Not native

Comment: Well where's the other answers giving a solution? I don't see any, and as its possible to mix native code when using Titanium maybe this should be tried to see if it solves the problem before down voting (especially because Titanium relies on native UI and controls). If a Titanium specific answer gets posted then ok, but I'm not seeing one so far.

Comment: Titanium is JavaScript. If you want to use native code, you would have to dive in deeper into titanium. For this to be a valid answer at least give directions on how to do this with titanium and how to include this in JavaScript.